# Is there a .net core global tool for gRPC?

Tags: .net-core, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, grpc, protoc

I've just started with gRPC, but it seems that running `protoc` is a common enough task to warrant a .net core global tool so that one can run something like this from the command line:

`dotnet protoc ...`

Is there such a thing?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would this `dotnet protoc` do that `protoc` doesn't? Is it just about the naming convenience?

Comment: It would *do* nothing differently.  It'd just be easier to *retrieve* and *use*.

Comment: What do you mean by ease of use? Would it be a different tool with different options? Consider the maintenance burden of maintaining such a tool so that it's easy to retrieve. A maintainer would have to keep the nuget package up to date with all the updates to the mainline grpc tool. They would have to build/package it for multiple architectures and platforms. It would be another place to fix for security issues in grpc. Why do you think Microsoft is not doing a `dotnet-npm` tool when even the default .NET Core templates are using npm?

Comment: We don't officialy support this, but there is some ongoing work that would help integrating protoc codegen with msbuild: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/pull/13207   There's also a community-provided package https://github.com/hcoona/Grpc.Tools.MsBuild.Unofficial.